# Automating Google Apps Signup

Tags: email, g-suite

I would like to like to create a Google Apps Standard account for my customers when they purchase a domain so that I don't need to hassle with maintaining a mail server. The process of purchasing a domain is automated. I would like to be able to automate the Google Apps signup also. Does anyone know if this is possible? Is there an API available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Account provisioning APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_developers_protocol.html) are available, but only for Premier and Education Editions - *not* Standard Edition.

[This chart](http://code.google.com/apis/apps/start.html) gives an overview of what services are available for each edition.

Comment: I'd check their terms of use... automated signup may be a violation if you don't have access to the account provisioning APIs. But, on the other hand... if you're selling domains, why not just setup a mail server? Surely customers would want to access everything through one place, and perhaps expect features (and support) that you can't give through Google.

Comment: It doesn't look like that will allow me to create accounts for new domains, but just lets you manage an existing account. It doesn't look like I'll be able to do what I had hoped, and will probably have to set up a mail server instead.